# Using object of imported class as global variable of another class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, global-variables

I have run into the following issue in Python. Suppose you have 3 files:

1) a.py (defines class A):

```
class A:
  def a_method(self):
    print "global var experiment"
```

2) b.py (defines class B that uses method of the global object of class A):

```
class B:
  def b_method(self):
    print "calling a_method() from B..."
      obj_a.a_method()
```

3) global_ex.py:

```
from a import A

obj_a=A()       
obj_a.a_method()

from b import B

obj_b = B()
obj_b.b_method()
```

When I run global_ex.py I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'obj_a' is not defined
```

If instead of importing a.py and b.py I copy-paste them into the global_ex.py it works fine.

What is the issue here?
Generally, What is the best way to use methods of one object in another object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: well, `obj_a` is not defined in the global scope of `b.py` - would you like the interpreter to copy-paste the text of the imported module instead of using compiled bytecode?

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

Try:

```
from a import A

class B():

  def __init__(self):
      self.a_obj = A()

  def b_method(self):
      print "calling a_method() from B..."
      self.a_obj.a_method()
```

Or:

```
class B():

  def __init__(self, a_inst):
      self.a_inst = a_inst

  def b_method(self):
      print "calling a_method() from B..."
      self.a_inst.a_method()
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I gave a simple example here. In my real case class A contains other members and methods which should be accessible by other classes. Right now I am thinking that maybe the best way would be to pass obj_A as and argument to b_method. It should work that way, shouldn't it?

Comment: @GregoryR - yes, it would work the way you mentioned and it one of the use-cases

Comment: @GregoryR: Instead of passing `obj_a` to `b_method()` every time you call it, you could also add an `__init__()` method to `class B` and pass `obj_a` to it just once when you construct `obj_b` -- of course `__init__()` would have to save the value for access later in `b_method` as needed something like what is shown in the second example of this answer.

Comment: @martineau: Thanks. When I pass obj_a to __init__() of class B, is it passed by reference? (In other words, if obj_a gets updated, will class B be aware of these updates?)

Comment: @GregoryR: Yes, since it's an instance of a mutable class.

Comment: Artsiom: While I think something like your second suggestion is fine, FYIW I don't think your first one is reasonable -- deriving one class from another just to obtain attribute access doesn't seem like a good design to me.

Comment: @martineau i agree with you, it was given since i thought that OP needs a bit more than just(i guess that they have more in common) one function call - and this was my fault

Comment: Artsiom: Well, the common reason in object-oriented programming to use [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29) is because an "[is a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)" relationship exists between the two classes, which I doubt is the case here especially given that the two classes are being defined in separate files (although that alone doesn't rule it out). Seems much more likely to be a ["has-a"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) relationship. +1 for your revised answer.